# NHibernate session handler with Autofac in a Windows service

Tags: windows, nhibernate, autofac

I have a Mvc system working fine with NHibernate and Autofac... I´m doing that to manage the NH sessions :

```
public static void Init(Assembly assembly)
{            
     var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

     builder.RegisterControllers(assembly);

     builder.Register(x => NHibernateInitializer.BuildSessionFactory()).SingleInstance();
     builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InstancePerHttpRequest();

     builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
     var container = builder.Build();
     DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

}
```

Now I need to configure a Windows Service to use NHibernate, but I´m not sure if It is possible with Autofac. 
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how the service is going to maintain the lifetime of the NH session. Will it use a single session for its entire run? Open a new session per operation? Something else? What is appropriate for your program?

Comment: I´d like to open a new session per operation. My service will be running and waiting for an action. So it opens a session and save some obj in db. I think its the best solution.

Comment: You may need to clarify your question. If the question is, "Is it _possible_ to use Autofac and NHibernate in a Windows Service?" then the answer is yes. If you need some other sort of info, it might be good to explain what exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would register `ISession` and other services as `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()` and then have each operation be run in its own child LifetimeScope. This would ensure that all the `IDisposable` services get cleaned up nicely at the end of the operation.

Comment: How can I run each operation in a different scope?

Comment: assuming your service has a reference to the container. wrap your method in a `using (var operationScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope()) { ... }` and then resolve your ISession from that scope.